# An infinite sum involving Harmonic sum squared $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^2_n}{n^2}$

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

I want to find the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^2_n}{n^2}$$

For some background context. I recently found the Taylor series of Dilogarithm squared as

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)^2=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2nH^{(2)}_{n-1}+4H_{n-1}}{n^3}\right)x^n$$

Where $$H_n^{(m)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^m}$$

This can be derived from expanding $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ in series form, square it and use cauchy product

The interesting thing is that if $x=1$ I found that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^2}=\frac{7\pi^4}{360}$$

So I'm wondering if I can find the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H^2_n}{n^2}$$

I've tried to use the fact that

$$\frac{H^{(2)}_n+H^2_n}{n}=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_k}{k}$$

and take the sum on both sides but failed because I couldn't handle the sum right hand side.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @TymaGaidash Sorry it should be n